# WPF Core with Autofac dependency injection - migrations error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, autofac

I'm trying to get Autofac dependency injection for ef core in a WPF Core 3.1 app but I cannot do any migrations.

I keep getting this error when trying to add migrations through CLI:

Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Any suggestion?

Those are my methods:

Startup Class:

```
 public partial class App : Application
    {
        public IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; private set; }

        private void App_OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
            serviceCollection.AddTransient(typeof(MainWindow));
            ServiceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
            var bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper(ServiceProvider);
            var container = bootstrapper.Bootstrap();
            var mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
            //var mainWindow = new MainWindow(
            //    new RecruitmentViewModel(new ContractorDataService()));
            mainWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

Bootstrapper which acts like a start-up

```
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public Bootstrapper(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        public IContainer Bootstrap()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
            var configuration = config.Build();


            builder.RegisterType<MainWindow>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<RecruitmentViewModel>().AsSelf();
            builder.RegisterType<ContractorDataService>().As<IContractorDataService>();

            RegisterContext<ApplicationDbContext>(builder, configuration);

            return builder.Build();
        }
        public void RegisterContext<TContext>(ContainerBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
            where TContext : DbContext
        {
            builder.Register(componentContext =>
            {
                var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptions<TContext>(new Dictionary<Type, IDbContextOptionsExtension>());
                var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>(dbContextOptions)
                    .UseApplicationServiceProvider(_serviceProvider)
                    .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                        serverOptions => serverOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), null));

                return optionsBuilder.Options;
            }).As<DbContextOptions<TContext>>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.Register(context => context.Resolve<DbContextOptions<TContext>>())
                .As<DbContextOptions>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

            builder.RegisterType<TContext>()
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
```